How install intl extension on MacOS and enable it on XAMPP
Environment:
O.S.: macOS Sonoma 14.5
Xampp: 8.2.4-0

PHP Version:
php --version
PHP 8.2.4 (cli) (built: Apr  6 2023 04:12:41) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Tried to install package using brew:
sudo pecl install intl

But this command fails. This is the last part of error log
/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_sort.h:23:39: note: to match this '('
typedef int (*collator_compare_func_t)( zval *result, zval *op1, zval *op2 TSRMLS_DC );
                                      ^
In file included from /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c:25:
/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found
#include <unicode/ubrk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

During installation, script ask me:
Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] : 

I click ENTER...a
Please help me to found a solution. I need to enable "Local" Class for my Application:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Locale" not found

Thanks in advance

You should install icu4c first.

did you fix that @Luca?
